# Let $a>0$ and $z_{1}>0$. Let $z_{n+1}=[a+z_{n}]^{1/2}$ for $n \in N$. Determine if $z_{n}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a>0$ and $z_{1}>0$. Let $z_{n+1}=[a+z_{n}]^{1/2}$ for $n \in N$. Determine if $z_{n}$ converges or diverges?

I am trying to solve it using monotone convergence theorem.

If I let $z_{1} = a^{1/2}$

Then it is easy to show $z_{n}$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above by $1+2*{a}^{1/2}$ and hence convergent.

But I am unable to prove it as a whole for $z_{1}>0$

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If the series converges to a limit $L$ then this limit satisfies
$$L=\sqrt{a+L}\ ,$$
that is, $L^2-L-a=0$, and so
$$L=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}\ ,$$
where we have chosen the positive root since clearly $L\ge0$.

Now we prove that this really is the limit.  We have
$$\eqalign{
  z_{n+1}-L
  &=\sqrt{a+z_n}-L\cr
  &=\frac{z_n+a-L^2}{\sqrt{a+z_n}+L}\cr
  &=\frac{z_n-L}{\sqrt{a+z_n}+L}\cr}$$
and so
$$|z_{n+1}-L|<\frac1L|z_n-L|\ .$$
We have by induction
$$|z_{n+1}-L|<\frac1{L^n}|z_1-L|$$
and since $L>1$, the right hand side tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.  Therefore $z_n\to L$ as $n\to\infty$.